# Bash associative array has elements that are not defined in them

Tags: bash

I have a bash command that receives an associative array from python:

```
string=$(/path/to/my-profiles.py --my-profiles setenv)
echo $string
>>> ( ['SOME_ENV']='1' )

declare -A env=string

for i in "${!env[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${env[$i]}"
done


>>>key  : SOME_ENV
value: 1
key  : 0
value: array
```

I didn't add key, value of 0 and array into the associative array. How to avoid this ?

Comment: `array` is not an array; it's just a string that looks like associative-array assignment syntax.

Comment: Yes, its a string

Comment: please update the question with the output from `typeset -p string` so we can see *exactly* what's stored in variable `string`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> declare -A env=array
> ```

Assigns the **string** `array` to variable `env`. All variables are one element arrays with index zero. Because `env` is an array, the string gets assigned to the element with index `0`.

Check variables values with `declare -p env`.

> How to avoid this ?

Is unclear. To not assign to a key `0`, actually assign an element with some value to the array.

```
declare -A env=( [something]=somethingelse )
```

Comment: I do not want the key, value pair associated with index 0. So, how can I filter it while I iterate in for loop ?

Comment: I do not understand the comment. You can filter by comparing the elements while iterating.

Comment: @NewToCoding you may be looking for `declare -A env=$array` when you initialize it. This probably isn't foolproof but handles simple cases well enough.

Comment: @tjm3772 Thank you, this is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the content of the `string` variable looks like:

```
declare -- string="( [SOME_ENV]=1 )"
```

A small change to OP's `declare -A` statement:

```
declare -A env="${string}"
```

This gives us:

```
$ typeset -p env
declare -A env=([SOME_ENV]="1" )

$ for i in "${!env[@]}"; do   echo "key  : $i";   echo "value: ${env[$i]}"; done
key  : SOME_ENV
value: 1
```